# How to query fields in a fieldset

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, soql

I am trying to get fields available on a fieldset in my query, the reason is we are using a managed package that can end up in an infinite loop if the fieldset is empty, we have hundreds of fieldsets in our org and it would be very helpful if we can at a glance know which one was not created properly or have empty fields, from a previous post I was able to get the below tooling API query that gave a lot of info for each fieldset, however I don't know how I can incorporate the fields within that fieldset in this query, any help would be extremely helpful

```
SELECT EntityDefinitionId, EntityDefinition.Namespaceprefix, EntityDefinition.DeveloperName, 
    Id, DeveloperName, Description, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name
FROM FieldSet where EntityDefinition.DeveloperName='Loan' and developername like 'UI_R1%'
ORDER BY EntityDefinitionId, Id
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to query `FieldSetMember` table with normal SOQL or Tooling API. You could implement the Metadata API to fetch sObject definitions similar to how they're stored in Eclipse.

[image]

I think they didn't build API access to it because it wasn't needed much. In Apex this data is quite easy to obtain with "describe" calls if you follow the [fieldsets tutorial](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm). So apart from metadata API this would give you options to

- build a REST resource which you could call similar to Tooling API query, pass to it objects you're interested in and it'd reply with fieldsets
- build a VF page that does similar thing (maybe even without any Apex required) - you'd still need a valid session id to pull such page's content to Excel so in a way it's not too different from REST url.

---

So, do you feel like doing a bit of coding?
Here's the basic example on how to expose a piece of Apex as REST service & call it: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm

As for actual logic - experiment with this in `ExecuteAnonymous` to get a feel of things?

```
// Pull it from GET request parameters?
List<String> types = new List<String>{'Account','Equipment__c'};

// if empty - describe it all (can be an expensive operation!)
// you'll get hundreds of objects back, might want to filter it down a bit by namespace?
if(types == null || types.isEmpty()){
    types = new List<String>(Schema.getGlobalDescribe().keyset());
}

// sObject => Fieldset Name => fields
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> abomination = new Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>();

for(Schema.DescribeSobjectResult dsr : Schema.describeSObjects(types)){
    Map<String, List<String>> temp = new Map<String, List<String>>();
    Map<String, Schema.FieldSet> fieldsets =  dsr.fieldSets.getMap();
    for(String fieldsetName : fieldsets.keyset()){
        List<String> fields = new List<String>();
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : fieldsets.get(fieldsetName).getFields()){
            fields.add(f.getFieldPath());
        }
        temp.put(fieldsetName, fields);
    }
    abomination.put(dsr.getName(), temp);
}

System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(abomination));
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand the concept - but I will need to dig into the REST API Call which is a bit new to me and also very exciting if I can have it working - will follow up the steps on the link you provided, for the VF Page option, I have already used that to render a VF Page based on the fieldset members before but I would be more inclined to use a query and get a response as we have hundreds of filedsets in our Org - thanks again

Comment: Check REST trailheads: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_webservices